# Database table(s) to record investor activity

Tags: database-design, ms-access

I've never asked a question here before.

I am currently designing my first database by learning from the web and some books I got, using MS Access to start. I work in operations for a small hedge fund with about 100 investors and I want to upgrade from scattered Excel sheets to a proper database. Initially I plan on using the database for managing investor relations and/or keeping track of money movements.

I think I have table design, keys, and normalization figured out. I created a table with beginning balances as of 1/31/2016. What is the best model for me to use to record future transactions? For example, an investor adding or withdrawing money, profits every month from trading, a list of future investor contributions, etc. I'm not finding answers online, because "transactions" apparently means logs in this world.

Is there a good resource out there or a standard design out there, so I don't have to re-invent the wheel?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I see that my question is too vague.

I am attaching an example of my relationships.

Did I set up the Docs, Transaction Types, and Transactions correctly?

Thanks!

[image: Access diagram of table relationships]

Comment: Having worked in the financial sector before, I can tell you that storing this sort of data in MS Access probably isn't going to cut it as far as regulations for storing historical data, proper PII data anonymizing, and security overall. 
Aside from this, your question is pretty vague and it's going to be hard to help you without more specific details. If you have a data structure in mind, post it - but don't expect us to help you design an entire database.

Comment: Also, Access does't really scale well to even 10 simultaneous active users, much less 100.

Comment: My best advice is: start as small and simple as you can. The task you're working on is potentially *huge*, so identify a single, specific problem to solve first, then add to your solution over time as you learn. Other than that, I'll agree with @JohnM that this question is too vague as it stands to really give you a good answer on a Q&A site like StackExchange, so I'm voting to close it on that basis. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll start small and if I run into a specific problem like you mentioned i'll ask.

Comment: Just edited to clarify question.